# How do I use a ruby on rails find method in my view or is that bad practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rubygems

So I was implementing a feature that allows users to set default profile photos and default photo album cover photos.

Completed these features now:

I have the following tables in my database:
**User(s)** (has one profile, has many PhotoAlbums) 
**Profile(s)** (belongs to user) contains photo_id 
**PhotoAlbum(s)** (belongs to user, has many photos) contains photo_id 
**Photo(s)** (belongs to PhotoAlbum)

Displaying the users default photo is straight forward.
I'm having trouble displaying the users default album photo now.

This is how I display users default profile photo:

UsersController:

```
default_profile_photo_id = current_user.profile.photo_id
 @default_photo = Photo.find(default_profile_photo_id)
```

Users view show template:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(@default_photo.image, :width =>"200"), @user.username %>
```

Currently for photoalbums default photos I show the first photo inside that photo album:

```
   <% for photo_album in @photoalbums %>
   <%= link_to photo_album.album_title, photo_album %>    
   <%= link_to image_tag(photo_album.photos.first.image, :width =>"100"), photo_album %>
   <%= link_to "Edit Album", edit_photo_album_path(photo_album) %> 
   <%= photo_album.photos.size %>
   <% end %>
```

Associated controller action:

```
  def index
    @photoalbums = PhotoAlbum.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
  end
```

What I need to do is during the for loop, pull the row from the photos table that has an id that matches the photo_id of the photoalbum that the loop is currently looping so that on my index template I can pull the image from the matching photo row and display it.

I've tried endless solutions but none work..

I feel I need a helping hand from an experienced programmer.

Kind regards

Comment: Can't you just add `belongs_to :photo` to the album (since it already has a `photo_id` column)  and display it with `photo_album.photo`?

Comment: FYI, instead of `Photo.find(default_profile_photo_id)`, you can do `current_user.profile.photo`. Same for `PhotoAlbum.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)`, you can use `current_user.photo_albums` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PhotoAlbum model:

```
belongs_to :photo
```

view:

```
image_tag(photo_album.photo(photo_album.photo_id).image
```

Very, very simple fix inspired by Frederick Cheungs comment.

Answer (score 0):

One efficient way of doing this would be to add a default_photo to albums which you set on save to be the first photo.

```
class PhotoAlbum
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :photos
  belongs_to :default_photo

  before_save :set_default_photo

  protected
    def set_default_photo
      self.default_photo = self.photos.first
    end
end
```

Then in your controller, you can just include the default photo in your query.

```
def index
  @photo_albums = current_user.photo_albums.include(:default_photo)
end
```

That way, in your view when you're calling `photo_album.default_photo`, it won't hit the database again because the default photo is already loaded.